# Dont know how to setup the php.ini include path for PEAR

Tags: php, wampserver, pear

Am having this error as i installed my pear package and to run the Numbers to word class.

> Warning: include(Numbers/Words.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

and this is my php.ini file include string

> ; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
>   include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;c:\php\pear"

Please i need help...it has taken most of my time here..

Comment: Did you install PEAR and if so where did you install it? Remember it does not come pre-installed on WAMPServer you need to install it.

Comment: I installed the PEAR in my php5.5.12 directory

Comment: and my PEAR has two directory...like if i open the first directory i see another PEAR directory dough the first one is small caps while the second one is big caps....please i need a clear understanding to this...thanks @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this line

```
include_path = ".;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\pear"
```

Edit:

Here are docs:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php#installation.checking.cli.modifyingphpini